# What is keyspace in redis ?

Tags: redis

I am new to redis, I do not know the meaning of "keyspace" and "key space" in redis  terminology which I encountered in redis official website. Can someone help me to clear that? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These terms refer to the internal dictionary that Redis manages, in which all keys are stored. The keyspace of a Redis database is managed by a single server in the case of a single instance deployment, and is divided to exclusive slot ranges managed by different nodes when using cluster mode.

Comment: does every key space has its own listener thread or is it shared between all kespaces?

Comment: What do you mean by "listener"?

Comment: Sorry, wrong wording. Ignore the word "listener", the question is if Redis uses the same thread for all key spaces or a separate thread for each keyspace. Would KEYS * on one keyspace block the other?

Comment: A single Redis instance, whether standalone or clustered, has a single keyspace. In standalone mode, the keyspace can be further logically segmented into logical databases ("namespaces"), but they are all a part of the same keyspace. Redis is mostly single-threaded, where single means the data access path for all writes and most reads. So yeah, single-threaded would be your answer, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

In a key-value database, all keys can be in one node or divided in multiple nodes. Suppose I am storing telephone dictionary as key-value store with name as key and phone number as a value. If I store names A-L on one node and M-Z on another node, I divide my database into two key spaces. When I run query to search number of Smith, I need to search only second key space or node. This divides the query on multiple nodes and divide the work giving faster result. This could be shared-nothing model of working.